# Как установить максимальный размер текста,чтоб не было переносов в TextView

Tags: android

добрый день.
 Есть 3 TextView, которые между собой в равной мере делят ширину экрана.  Текст в каждой состоит из 2 строк. Текст определен в строковой переменной в виде 
 `<string name="str">Striiiiiiing\nstring</string>`
 Хотелось бы подобрать максимальный размер текста, при котором верхняя строка отображалась без переноса. 
 Как это сделать? Возможно ли определить ширину текста в пикселях, при определенном размере шрифта? Или возможно определить что был выполнен перенос?

======================================

Спасибо Kazemir.

Для решения использовал ответ Kazemir с небольшим дополнение

 Для api26

```
<TextView
   .......
 android:maxLines="2"
 android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
 android:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
 android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
 android:autoSizeStepGranularity="1sp"
 android:text="@string/str" />
```

Для более младших версий можно пользоваться библиотекой поддержки

```
 app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
 app:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
 app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
 app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
```

Что бы не было переноса слов надо выставить количество строк `android:maxLines`.
 В моем случае 2 строки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Привет.

Думаю, самый нормальный вариант - это создать кисть (Paint или TextPaint) и через функцию [measureText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#measureText(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int)) измерить ширину текста в пикселях. Ну и постепенно инкрементить через [setTextSize()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setTextSize(float)) размер текста у кисти. А там уже дело техники:)

Ещё есть такие штуки, как [StaticLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/StaticLayout.html) и [Autosizing TextViews](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview.html), но не думаю, что они подходят к этому случаю.

Comment: Зря так думаешь  Autosizing TextViews самое то, спасибо большое